# Why are symbols not displaying after adding them via the Python Console?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, symbology, qgis-python-console

Steps to reproduce:

Create a new project->Add new Shapefile Layer(Polygon)->Click on the newly added Layer->Toggle Editing->Using the 'Add Feature' Tool draw a polygon and save the layer

Open the python console->Run the following lines of code in the python console

```
from PyQt4.QtGUI import QColor

layer = iface.activeLayer()
symbol = QgsLineSymbolV2.createSimple({})
symbol.deleteSymbolLayer(0)
symbol_layer = QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayerV2(QColor('red'), 2.0)
symbol.appendSymbolLayer(symbol_layer.clone())
layer.rendererV2().setSymbol(symbol.clone())
layer.triggerRepaint()
iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)
```

After running the above code the polygon stops displaying. Is this a bug in QGIS 2.18 or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can't successfully apply a `QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayerV2()` symbol to a polygon because it belongs to linestring geometries.

The allowed symbols for polygons are:

- Simple fill (`QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayerV2`);
- Gradient fill (`QgsFillSymbolLayerV2`);
- Centroid fill (`QgsCentroidFillSymbolLayerV2`);
- Line pattern fill (`QgsLinePatternFillSymbolLayer`);
- Point pattern fill (`QgsPointPatternFillSymbolLayer`);
- SVG fill (`QgsSVGFillSymbolLayer`);
- Outline: marker line (`QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayerV2`);
- Outline: simple line (`QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayerV2`).

Comment: According to your response QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayerV2 can not be successfully applied to a polygon. If this is the case why are including it in your list of allowed symbols for polygons? Your answer is confusing!

Comment: Thanks for your response you helped me figure out the answer to my question.

Comment: @SoftwareGuy you are welcome. If you want to perform any specific operation with symbol layer I will try to help you (but you should ask a new separate question).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with my code above is the symbol I was using. Once I changed the symbol to use the QgsLinePatternFillSymbolLayer object polygon displayed on the layer as expected.